# How to draw String into Image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get picture from Camera using image_picker library, then I want to add information of the date and time the picture was taken into the image..?
Is that possible..? Thank you..

Comment: what exactly do you want? Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to display an image using image_picker and store its date and time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can draw string into image using [image 2.1.12](https://pub.dev/packages/image)

You have to import below library in your dart file

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
```

Function for capture image and draw string on image

```
  Future<File> drawTextOnImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    var decodeImg = img.decodeImage(image.readAsBytesSync());

    img.drawString(decodeImg, img.arial_48, 0, 0, DateTime.now().toString());

    var encodeImage = img.encodeJpg(decodeImg, quality: 100);

    var finalImage = File(image.path)..writeAsBytesSync(encodeImage);

    return finalImage;
  }
```

Comment: just replace this line `var decodeImg = img.decodeImage(image.readAsBytesSync());` to `var decodeImg = img.decodeImage(File(image.path).readAsBytesSync());` because `readAsBytesSync` method not support XFile