# Flutter - Drawstring on captured photo from camera

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am using this https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki to try and draw text on my image my question is how do I get the image needed for the first parameter in Image.drawString() when the image I am trying to pass is the one that is captured by the camera plugin?

```dart
final path = join(
  // Store the picture in the temp directory.
  // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
  (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
  '${DateTime.now()}.png',
);

// Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved.
await _controller.takePicture(path);
//this doesnt work
img.Image image = Image.file(File(path)) 
img.drawString(image, img.arial_24, 50, 50, "Hello World");
```

I am getting this error:

> 'Image (where Image is defined in
> myflutterpath/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart)' can't be
> assigned to a variable of type 'Image (where Image is defined in
> /myflutterpath/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.4/lib/src/image.dart)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw String into Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979213/how-to-draw-string-into-image)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an `Image` widget from Flutter to a `img.Image` variable from the `image` package. These are completely separate data types.

To do what you want, you need to create an `img.Image` object. Since your image source is a PNG file(guessing based on file extension), you'll need to decode it to raw pixel data. This can be done with the [`PngDecoder`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/PngDecoder-class.html) that's already included in the `image` package that you have.

```dart
img.Image image = img.PngDecoder().decodeImage(await File(path).readAsBytes());
```

This creates an `img.Image` from your PNG file instead of an `Image` widget.